# How to remove bullets using corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to remove a bullet once it's shot, just after my transition. Here is my code:

```
local bullet
local function shootf (event)

  bullet = display.newRect(w/2, h/2, 15, 15)
  physics.addBody( bullet, "static")
  transition.to( bullet, {time = speed, x = bulletX, y = bulletY})
  print( "bullet shot" )
end

shoot:addEventListener("tap", shootf)
```

How can remove properly the bullet? I tried several things but I don't know how to handle de remove functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `transition.to` as follows, and run the app:

```
transition.to( bullet, {time = speed,
                         x = bulletX,
                         y = bulletY,
                         onComplete=function() bullet:removeSelf() end end})
```

Keep Coding............. :)